# How to convert a viewbag which is a list to a SelectList if the viewbag is empty - null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I deal with an empty viewbag that is a list and it can sometimes be empty - a null?

I get the error: "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".

I have an MVC application and passing a viewbag (which is a list) as an argument.

At times it can be empty.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, movieGenre = (SelectList)ViewBag.movieGenre, searchString = ViewBag.searchString.toString() }))
```

Comment: You cannot pass a `SelectList` to your method using `Url.Action()` - its a collection of complex objects - look at the query string it generates when its not empty/ What are you really trying to do here. Assuming you have a dropdownlist in the view for filtering, then you need to pass the value or the selected option (see the links I gave you in the chat session of your previous question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a default value from the ViewBag if it is null.
`(Viewbag.something ?? 'This is the value if Viewbag.something is null')`

Answer (score 0):

You must first attempt to pull the value from the viewbag and initialize it to an empty `SelectList` if the value is not there.

Please this code anywhere before the `PagedListPager` call:

```
@{
    SelectList movieGenre = (ViewBag.movieGenre == null) ? new SelectList(new List<string>()) : ViewBag.movieGenre;
}
```

Then use that instance in your rendering call:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, movieGenre, searchString = ViewBag.searchString.toString() }))
```

Please note your `searchString` property might have the same problem.